# Проблема с программой на python

Tags: python

Решил написать небольшую текстовую игру для тренировки, но возникла проблема. Когда я запускаю программу, всё вроде бы работает, но в какой-то момент программа (как я понимаю) уходит в бесконечный цикл. Можете ли объяснить, в чём моя ошибка? [image: показано на картинке]

```
import random as r

patience_of_the_people = 0
eurasia = True
ost = False

def print_patience():
    print('На данный момент терпение народа составляет {0}!'.format(patience_of_the_people))

def what_q():
    global patience_of_the_people
    global eurasia
    global ost

    q = ['С кем война?', 'С кем мир?']
    choice_q = r.choice(q)
    print('Сейчас у тебя команда:', choice_q)

    while True:
        if choice_q == 'С кем война?':
            u_choice = input().lower()
            if (u_choice == 'евразия' and eurasia) or (u_choice == 'остазия' and ost):
                patience_of_the_people += 1
                print('Вы правы! Репутация правительства в народе увеличилась!')
                print_patience()
                break
            else:
                patience_of_the_people -= 1
                print('Вы неправы! Репутация правительства в народе уменьшилась!')
                break
        elif choice_q == 'С кем мир?':
            u_choice = input().lower()
            if (u_choice == 'евразия' and not eurasia) or (u_choice == 'остазия' and not ost):
                patience_of_the_people += 1
                print('Вы правы! Репутация правительства в народе увеличилась!')
                print_patience()
                break
            else:
                patience_of_the_people -= 1
                print('Вы неправы! Репутация правительства в народе уменьшилась!')
                break

def replacement():
    global patience_of_the_people
    global eurasia
    global ost

    while True:
        u_choice2 = input().lower()
        if u_choice2 == 'заменить':
            patience_of_the_people -= 2
            eurasia, ost = ost, eurasia
            print('Вы выполнили указания правительства, однако народ недоволен из-за новой войны...')
            print_patience()
            break
        else:
            continue

def propaganda():
    global patience_of_the_people

    while True:
        u_choice3 = input().lower()
        if u_choice3 == 'организовать':
            patience_of_the_people += 1
            print('Пропаганда сработала на ура!')
            print_patience()
            break
        else:
            continue

def in_game(inPatience):
    global patience_of_the_people
    patience_of_the_people = inPatience

    print('Добро пожаловать в текстовый квест, посвящённый произведению Джорджа Оруэла «1984»!')
    print('Именно отсюда начинается твоя работа в Минитерстве Правды. Удачи!')
    print('По стандарту война с Евразией и мир с Остазией')
    print_patience()

def loop_for_game():
    situation = r.randint(0, 10)

    if situation == 1:
        what_q()
    elif situation == 2:
        replacement()
    elif situation == 3:
        propaganda()
    else:
        input('Вы сидите в своём кабинете в полном уединении...')

in_game(10)

while True:
    loop_for_game()

    if patience_of_the_people <= 0:
        if input('Восстание населения Океании завершило тоталитарный режим. Хотите попробовать ещё раз? (да/нет) :').lower() == 'да':
            in_game(10)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: заранее извиняюсь за не самый хороший код

Comment: В первую очередь у вас только в одном режиме оно что-то спрашивает понятное, а в двух других просто ждёт ввода, а что именно вводить и зачем - непонятно. Пишите в `input()` какую-нибудь надпись что ли - что нужно ввести.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: зачем вы делаете цикл `while True:` в функциях `replacement()`, `propaganda()`, `what_q()` ?

Answer (score 0):

чуть-чуть подправил ваш код чтобы было понятно, что происходит:

в общем в функциях `replacement` и `propaganda` требуется ввод команд, но не отображается никакая информация до ввода - гадай, что происходит

а "зацикливания" происходят потому что у вас

```
situation = r.randint(0, 10)
```

и только на 3 из них срабатывает вызов функций с вопросами или командами, т.е. 70% циклов ничего не происходит, это и можно принять за зацикливание

```
import random as r

patience_of_the_people = 0
eurasia = True
ost = False

def print_patience():
    print(f'На данный момент терпение народа составляет {patience_of_the_people}!')

def what_q():
    global patience_of_the_people
    global eurasia
    global ost

    q = ['С кем война?', 'С кем мир?']
    choice_q = r.choice(q)
    print('Сейчас у тебя команда:', choice_q)

    if choice_q == 'С кем война?':
        u_choice = input().lower()
        if (u_choice == 'евразия' and eurasia) or (u_choice == 'остазия' and ost):
            patience_of_the_people += 1
            print('Вы правы! Репутация правительства в народе увеличилась!')
            print_patience()
        else:
            patience_of_the_people -= 1
            print('Вы неправы! Репутация правительства в народе уменьшилась!')
    elif choice_q == 'С кем мир?':
        u_choice = input().lower()
        if (u_choice == 'евразия' and not eurasia) or (u_choice == 'остазия' and not ost):
            patience_of_the_people += 1
            print('Вы правы! Репутация правительства в народе увеличилась!')
            print_patience()
        else:
            patience_of_the_people -= 1
            print('Вы неправы! Репутация правительства в народе уменьшилась!')

def replacement():
    global patience_of_the_people
    global eurasia
    global ost

    while True:
        u_choice2 = input('<заменить> ').lower()
        if u_choice2 == 'заменить':
            patience_of_the_people -= 2
            eurasia, ost = ost, eurasia
            print('Вы выполнили указания правительства, однако народ недоволен из-за новой войны...')
            print_patience()
            break

def propaganda():
    global patience_of_the_people

    while True:
        u_choice3 = input('<пропаганда> ').lower()
        if u_choice3 == 'организовать':
            patience_of_the_people += 1
            print('Пропаганда сработала на ура!')
            print_patience()
            break

def in_game(inPatience):
    global patience_of_the_people
    patience_of_the_people = inPatience

    print('Добро пожаловать в текстовый квест, посвящённый произведению Джорджа Оруэла «1984»!')
    print('Именно отсюда начинается твоя работа в Минитерстве Правды. Удачи!')
    print('По стандарту война с Евразией и мир с Остазией')
    print_patience()

def loop_for_game():
    situation = r.randint(0, 10)
    print(situation)

    if situation == 1:
        what_q()
    elif situation == 2:
        replacement()
    elif situation == 3:
        propaganda()
    else:
        input('Вы сидите в своём кабинете в полном уединении...')

in_game(10)

while True:
    loop_for_game()

    if patience_of_the_people <= 0:
        if input('Восстание населения Океании завершило тоталитарный режим. Хотите попробовать ещё раз? (да/нет) :').lower() == 'да':
            in_game(10)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 0):

у вас не идет цикл, у вас просто не попадается значение 1, 2 или 3

```
def loop_for_game():
    situation = r.randint(0, 10)

    if situation == 1:
        what_q()
    elif situation == 2:
        replacement()
    elif situation == 3:
        propaganda()
    else:
        input('Вы сидите в своём кабинете в полном уединении...')
```

попробуйте изменить значение

```
situation = r.randint(0, 10)
```

на

```
situation = r.randint(0, 3)
```

таким образом, у вас не должно быть длинных циклом, возможно будут пролеты, из 'Вы сидите в своём кабинете в полном уединении...' несколько раз подряд, но это нормально, вы просто проклацайте их через enter, надеюсь я смог вам помочь =)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)